# Netsuite : Is it Possible to Integrate Financial Reports like Balance Sheet API in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I'm attempting to obtain a profit and loss statement, or balance sheet, using REST Web Services within Netsuite.

I've been successful at calling unique ID records (customers, vendors, and their respective data), but now I'd like to be able to pull a set of financials for a specific period/entity. Is there a way I can do that using Python, Postman, or does REST Web Services not support that sort of functionality?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not possible. The reports are not exposed via the API. As a horrible workaround, what you might be able to do is schedule the report to be delivered to an email, and then parse the resulting CSV attached to the email.